# Know whenever there's the same amount of 1 and 0 one a string

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Interested in using bitwise operators to count number of 1s = 0s in a bit string.  If 1s = 0s then output.  Any ideas on using Java to accomplish this?  Thank you.

```
public void function(int binaryNumber) {
    BigInteger val = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(binaryNumber));
    val = val.abs();
    int count = val.bitCount();
    String binaryString = val.toString(2);

    System.out.println("count = " + count);
    System.out.println("bin = " + binaryString);
}
```

Comment: if # of 1s = val.bitCount() then # of 0s = binaryString.length() - val.bitCount(). any problems?

Comment: Try using a bit mask. (I am writing the full version of your answer soon)

Comment: How large is your largest expected number? Do you start counting total bits from the first 1 bit, or from the range for the type, eg `long` has 64 bits total no matter what the value is or does `2` have 2 bits total?

Comment: @Bohemian I have provided solutions that handles both BigInteger and primitive cases.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous That is not relevant or desirable. I am seeking to clarify the question, to make it more valuable. Shotgun answers only encourage poorly defined questions.

Comment: What is a "shotgun answer" (I deleted temporarily until I can fix my answer)? Does my (now deleted) answer count as a shotgun answer? Is this question "poorly defined"?

Comment: @Bohemian This question, and your actions on it, are being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368682/my-potential-shotgun-answer-to-a-poorly-defined-question). Feel free to weigh in and share your view.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous i imagine he means "scattergun approach"

Comment: @Erik thanks for the heads up. I have posted an [answer on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368696/256196).

Comment: Downvote: Can you please clarify whenver you are intending to use a BigInteger or a primitive int, and give an example of how would you use the "bit string."

Answer (score 2):

***Update:*** Display bit format as unsigned, added `long` and `BigInteger` versions, and added versions ignoring sign.

The `Integer` class has many `static` methods for doing bit-magic. No need to use `BigInteger`, if input is an `int`. `Long` has the same methods, if needed.

Here is a method for doing the test you want. It uses:

- [`bitCount(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int)) - Returns the **number of one-bits** in the two's complement binary representation of the specified `int` value.
- [`numberOfLeadingZeros(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros(int)) - Returns the **number of zero bits preceding the highest-order ("leftmost") one-bit** in the two's complement binary representation of the specified `int` value. Returns 32 if the specified value has no one-bits in its two's complement representation, in other words if it is equal to zero.
- [`SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#SIZE) - The number of bits used to represent an int value in two's complement binary form *(which we all know is 32)*.

Since we want to ignore leading zeroes, `SIZE - numberOfLeadingZeros` will tell us the actual number of bits used.

```
public static boolean oneBitsEqualsZeroBits(int value) {
    if (value == 0)
        return false;
    int bitsUsed = Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value);
    int oneBits = Integer.bitCount(value);
    int zeroBits = bitsUsed - oneBits;
    return (oneBits == zeroBits);
}
```

It can be shortened, though that's a bit obscure, but explainable. Assume 0s==1s, so `bitCount` is number of 1s + `bitCount` is number of 0s, i.e. `bitCount * 2` is number of bits used. Add number of leading zeroes and all bits of an `int` should be accounted for.

```
public static boolean oneBitsEqualsZeroBits(int value) {
    return (value != 0 && Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value) + 2 * Integer.bitCount(value) == 32);
}
```

Same for `long` version:

```
public static boolean oneBitsEqualsZeroBits(long value) {
    return (value != 0 && Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(value) + 2 * Long.bitCount(value) == 64);
}
```

For `BigInteger`, counting leading zeroes makes no sense, since without a fixed bit-width, there are no leading zeroes. Instead, we have a different method:

- [`bitLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength()): Returns the number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of this `BigInteger`, excluding a sign bit.

Since the sign bit is excluded, we have to add it back in, to be consistent with the `int` and `long` versions.

```
public static boolean oneBitsEqualsZeroBits(BigInteger value) {
    if (value.signum() == 0)
        return false;
    if (value.signum() > 0)
        return (2 * value.bitCount() == value.bitLength());
    return (2 * value.bitCount() == value.bitLength() + 1);
}
```

The 3 versions will treat negative values differently, since `int` and `long` will do sign-extension to 32 and 64 bits, respectively.

*Test (for `int` version only)*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(0, false);
    test(1, false);
    test(0b10, true);
    test(0b11, false);
    test(0b100, false);
    test(0b1000, false);
    test(0b1001, true);
    test(0b1010, true);
    test(0b1011, false);
    test(0b1100, true);
    test(0b1101, false);
    test(0b101010_11110000_00111100_00001111, true);
    test(0b11001100_01010101_01100110_11100010, true);
    test(0b11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111, false);
}

public static void test(int value, boolean expected) {
    boolean result = oneBitsEqualsZeroBits(value);
    System.out.printf("%11d %8x %-5s %3s %s%n", value, value, result,
                      (result == expected ? "OK" : "ERR"),
                      Integer.toUnsignedString(value, 2));
}
```

*Output (title added manually to answer)*

```
    Decimal      Hex Result    Binary
          0        0 false  OK 0
          1        1 false  OK 1
          2        2 true   OK 10
          3        3 false  OK 11
          4        4 false  OK 100
          8        8 false  OK 1000
          9        9 true   OK 1001
         10        a true   OK 1010
         11        b false  OK 1011
         12        c true   OK 1100
         13        d false  OK 1101
  720387087 2af03c0f true   OK 101010111100000011110000001111
 -866818334 cc5566e2 true   OK 11001100010101010110011011100010
         -1 ffffffff false  OK 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

**Ignoring sign**

If you want to compare 1s and 0s on the string representation of the number, ignoring the sign, i.e. on `abs(value)`, then you change the methods to apply `abs()`:

```
public static boolean oneBitsEqualsZeroBits(int value) {
    if (value == 0 || value == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return false;
    if (value < 0)
        value = -value;
    return (Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value) + 2 * Integer.bitCount(value) == 32);
}

public static boolean oneBitsEqualsZeroBits(long value) {
    if (value == 0 || value == Long.MIN_VALUE)
        return false;
    if (value < 0)
        value = -value;
    return (Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(value) + 2 * Long.bitCount(value) == 64);
}

public static boolean oneBitsEqualsZeroBits(BigInteger value) {
    value = value.abs();
    return (value.signum() != 0 && 2 * value.bitCount() == value.bitLength());
}
```

Comment: What about integers larger than the largest value of long? Your answer does not address this issue, sorry. He might have used biginteger for arbitrarily large integers.

Comment: In `-866818334` case, 1s = 16, 0s = 14.  Why true?  OP counts for absolute value.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous The method `public void function(int binaryNumber)` *cannot* take integers larger than the largest value of `long`, since the parameter is an `int`.

Comment: @saka1029 There are 16 of each: `11001100_01010101_01100110_11100010`. I've fixed the answer to correctly display the value as unsigned, same as the hex format.

Comment: `abs(-866818334) = 866818334 = 0b110011101010101001100100011110 (1s = 16, 0s = 14)

Comment: @saka1029 But the code is not doing `abs`. Look at the code. The value was given as `0b11001100_01010101_01100110_11100010`, which has 1s = 0s = 16. It is the number of 1s and 0s in the 4-byte (32-bit) `int` value.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you meant by "Bit String," but I assume it could mean a binary sequence of any length. In your original code, you are using a `BigInteger` object which does not support primitive bitwise operators such as `|, &&, ^`.

However, your implementation only supports ints with a maximum value of around two billion, or 31 binary digits, as ints have 32 bits and the leading bit is a sign bit not used in your question. Instead, simply let the function pass a `String` variable, and let `val = new BigInteger(val)`.

From your `binaryString`, which is the String being your binary representation of your `BigInteger`, you can simply loop through the characters and keep track of ones and zeroes. Simply add this code after `System.out.println("bin = " + binaryString);`:

```
int zeroes = 0;
int ones = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < binaryString.length(); k++) {
    if (binaryString.charAt(k) == '0')
        zeroes++;
    if (binaryString.charAt(k) == '1')
        ones++;
}
```

However, if you want to use "bitwise operators" for `BigIntegers`, use a *bit mask* and *shift* techniques to determine whether it contains a one or a zero. For the `BigInteger` version, consider using this code after `System.out.println("bin = " + binaryString);`:

```
int zeroes = 0;
int ones = 0;
int bitindex = 0;
BigInteger bitmask = new BigInteger(String.valueOf("1"));
// BigInteger supports bitLength().
while (bitindex <= val.bitLength()) {
    // Bit mask has all but one bit equal zero. The AND operation cancels all
    // the bits except the one bit equal to one.
    if (bitmask.and(val).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        zeroes++;
    else
        ones++;

    bitindex++;
    bitmask = bitmask.shiftLeft(1);
}
```

This can be done similarly for the int version (or long), considering that all the trailing zeroes are discarded:

```
int zeroes = 0;
int ones = 0;

long bitmask = 1;
// Loop stops once the one bit gone above the most significant one bit one the val
// because from that point the bitmask will always be greater than val
while (bitmask >= 0 && bitmask <= val) {
    if ((bitmask & val) == 0)
        zeroes++;
    else
        ones++;
    bitmask <<= 1; // Operator << means left shift
}
```

Comment: To reproduce the last method (the int/long version), simply enclose the body with the method header `public static void function(long val)`.

Comment: Hello, Perhaps my Java syntax is not accurate.  I am trying to determine if there are an equal number of 1s = 0s in a bit string.  I should set a limit of 1024 bits per bit string.  Please advise.

Comment: The most important point is **it isn't clear** what your "bit string" exactly should be. Is it simply the `String` representing the binary digits of a `BigInteger`, obtained through `String binaryString = val.toString(2)`? Or is it the simply the binary digits of a `BigInteger` it implicitly has, and that you are extracting the ones and zeroes through *bitwise operations*? Maybe that is the reason why your question is heavily downvoted, and I want you to salvage this post so I can remove your downvote as well as make our answers more relevant.

Comment: @user9817776: This can be shown direclty as the first sentence of my answer. Because of that I have to post three different versions, and it seems the second version is more relevant because it represents bitwise operations on an arbitarily large integer, including those larger than 1024 bits. The `long` primitive is 63 bits at the most , but I am keeping it up for similarity. Your best bet is to state what is a "bit string" and whether you are using bit manipulation of your BitInteger. Also, instead, simply let your function pass a String variable, and let `val = new BigInteger(val)`.

Comment: @user9817776: Once you read my notices carefully, can you please post your clarification on your question? I don't want to post three different versions of my answer just in hopes of solving the question for you. It will also bump the answer on top so new upvotes can potentially come in.